# How to get rid of SQL Server Invalid Object name error?

Tags: sql-server, insert, ssms

I'm trying to insert some data into a table within SQL Server.

Below is the query that I use, but I get an error

> 'Invalid Object Name'

in SQL Server Management Studio.

The table does exist within the list of tables, and my database is set to 'BC-TEST' as well.

[image]

When I type the exact same query again, it works:

[image]

Done some research, and a lot of posts are referring to either caching or the database that is not set to the correct one. However none of these seems to be the case here.

Can someone help me out?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are two different queries, they are not the exact same.

The first query insert into [...$packaging processing], while the other one, the second query insert into [....$packing processing]

if the second query works perfectly, then the correct table must be [....$packing processing]